# Getting Connection timeout error while connect to Raspberry pi from laptop through SSH

Tags: networking, ssh

My RPi is running `rpi_pisces_r3`. I am trying to get SSH setup.

I have connected the RPi to the router through LAN and from router to laptop via LAN itself to establish connection between RPi and laptop via SSH.

I have tried to connect to the Pi using PuTTY on my Windows 7 PC using the static ip `192.168.0.102`. PuTTY throws the following error message:

```
Network error: connection timed out
```

Additionally, when I execute the command `ping 192.168.0.104` in cmd prompt, I got the following message:

```
Pinging 192.168.0.104 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.102: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.100: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.100: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.100: Destination host unreachable.
Ping statistics for 192.168.0.104:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
```

Comment: Is the Pi at 192.168.0.100, 102 or 104? have you tried `pi@raspberrypi.local` in PuTTY (where `raspberrypi` is the hostname you've assigned to you Pi)? Can you log in to the Pi using a keyboard & monitor -- what is the actual IP address assigned to it and is the network working?